# Guzzle отправить пост и получить ответ

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, guzzle

Как отправить данные через POST - логин, пароль, прокси на URL и получить оттуда ответ?
пробую так, но получаю страницу полностью, а нужно получить данные, которые возвращает api

```
$client = new Client();
        $r = $client->request('POST', 'http://site/api', [
            'json' => ['login' => $request->login, 'password' => $request->password, 'proxy' => ['ip'=> '123', 'username' => '1234']]
        ]);
        $body = $r->getBody();
        echo $body;
        return false;
```

Comment: А какую именно страницу? Случайно не 404 или страницу ошибки ларавела?

Comment: спарсил странице адреса url

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так : `$body = $r->getBody()->getContents();`